# union type is not working in redux saga action types?

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-saga

My union type is this BoardsActionType:

```
 interface createBoardRequest {
  type: typeof CREATE_BOARD_REQUEST;
  payload: {
    name: string;
  };
}

interface createBoardSuccess {
  type: typeof CREATE_BOARD_SUCCESS;
  payload: {
    board: BoardType;
  };
}

interface createBoardFailure {
  type: typeof CREATE_BOARD_FAILURE;
  payload: {
    error: string;
  };
}

export type BoardsActionTypes =
  | createBoardRequest
  | createBoardSuccess
  | createBoardFailure;
```

which i am trying to use in redux saga, this is my code that gets the problem:

```
export function* createBoard(action: BoardsActionTypes) {
  try {
    const {
      data: { board }
    } = yield call(Api.boards.createBoard, action.payload.name); // ERROR HERE
    yield put({ type: CREATE_BOARD_SUCCESS, payload: { board } });
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({ type: CREATE_BOARD_FAILURE, error });
  }
}
```

I am getting the error on action.payload.name which says

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type '{ name: string; } | { board: BoardType; } | { error: string; }'
```

How do i fix it in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action that is passed to `createBoard` saga isn't actually union type. The `action` argument can only be a `createBoardRequest` so your type should be

```
export function* createBoard(action: createBoardRequest) {
  ...
```

In your original code since you've typed the `action` being passed to `createBoard` as your union type, typescript is properly raising an error since if `action` was `createBoardSuccess` then `action.payload.name` wouldn't exist.

You probably want to use the `BoardsActionType` type in whatever reducer is responding to `createBoardRequest`, `createBoardSuccess` and `createBoardFailure` but shouldn't be used to type the `action` argument to the `createBoard` saga.